# C++ how to solve class incomplete type when two class depends on each other

Tags: c++, class, handle

I am learning the design pattern now and I read the book Ruminations on C++. The following example is how to use the handle class to do some application.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

class Expr_node;
class Int_node;
class Unary_node;
class Binary_node;

class Expr {
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Expr&);

  Expr_node* p;
 public:
  Expr(int);
  Expr(const string&, Expr);
  Expr(const string&, Expr, Expr);
  Expr(const Expr&);
  Expr& operator=(const Expr&);
};

Expr::Expr(int n) {
  p = new Int_node(n);
}

Expr::Expr(const string& op, Expr t) {
  p = new Unary_node(op, t);
}

Expr::Expr(const string & op, Expr left, Expr right) {
  p = new Binary_node(op, left, right);
}

class Expr_node {
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const Expr_node&);

protected:
    virtual void print(ostream&) const = 0;
    virtual ~Expr_node() { }
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, const Expr_node& e) {
    e.print(o);
    return o;
}

class Int_node: public Expr_node {
  friend class Expr;

  int n;

  explicit Int_node(int k) : n(k) {}
  void print(ostream& o) const override { o << n;}
};

class Unary_node: public Expr_node {
  friend class Expr;
  string op;
  Expr opnd;
  Unary_node(const string& a, const Expr& b): op(a), opnd(b) {}
  void print(ostream& o) const override {o << "(" << op << *opnd << ")";}
};

class Binary_node: public Expr_node {
  friend class Expr;
  string op;
  Expr left;
  Expr right;
  Binary_node(const string& a, const Expr& b, const Expr& c): op(a), left(b), right(c) {}
  void print(ostream& o) const override { o << "(" << left << op << right << ")";}
};
```

In this example, I want to implement three different kinds of operation based on inheritance from `Expr_node` class. It is obvious that the `Int_node` is not well defined until its full definition. I am not sure how to solve this problem. It seems that there are a lot of errors involved in this book.

Comment: "the design pattern" ? there is more than one, which one are you dealing with?

Comment: you want to learn more about [*forward declarations*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c). Pro tip: Reduce your code amount before posting it. I haven't read it, it's too much.

Comment: Simply move `Expr::Expr(int)` so that it is after the defintion of `Int_node`.

Comment: You are implementing the Strategy Pattern.  friends and forward declarations are a cludge.  Look for a different example.

Comment: @pasbi The OP is using forward declarations in their code.

Comment: @john indeed, they do. However, they do it wrong. And that's why they want to learn more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question (beside the other considerations that are in the various comments) :

you need to implement  the definition of the  constructor taking a int parameter

```
Expr::Expr(int n) {
  p = new Int_node(n);
}
```

after the definition of the constructor Int_node(int n) which is in your example inlined in the declaration of the Int_node class here :

```
class Int_node: public Expr_node {
  friend class Expr;

  int n;

  explicit Int_node(int k) : n(k) {}
  void print(ostream& o) const override { o << n;}
};
```

Comment: You may want to note that this traditionally occurs by splitting the program into multiple files, with declarations in headers.

Comment: Yes, but in the other hand this example have the benefit to make understand when you must have a function defined (i.e before using it) and when having it declare is enough. (and that is de-corelated from header and implementation files)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the few things that I don't like in C++...

While this code is not okay

```
// a.h
struct B;
struct A {
    B f() { return B(); } // error: incomplete result type 'B'
};
struct B { int x; };
```

the following is fine if you put your code in two files

```
// a.h
struct B;
struct A {
    B f();
};
struct B { int x; };
// a.cpp
B A::f() { return B(); }
```

If you insist, you *can* put the definition of `A::f()` in the header file, as long as it's not *in-class*...

```
// a.h
struct B;
struct A {
    B f();
};
struct B { int x; };
// only after the complete definition of B
inline B A::f() { return B(); }
```

I've been telling myself it is what it is since the day I learned C++ in college.

Comment: This has always bothered me about C++ as well.